# Creating shared space for PBS Pro

Tags: linux, hpc, pbs

How do you create shared space across nodes?

I have a designated drive that I would like to use but maintain the ability to add additional drives later

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you are just starting out and do not have any specific performance requirements. Then probably the easiest way to go would be to start an NFS server on the head node and export your dedicate drive as an NFS file share to the nodes. Your nodes would be able to mount this share over the network under the same mountpoint.

If your dedicated drives are spread across the cluster, the problem obviously gets trickier. After you have become comfortable with NFS, have a look at parallel file systems such as Gluster FS.